# Trying to add to an array with a function in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

folks. I'm just starting to learn C# and I'm trying to practice my functions/methods as well as learn about arrays, so I'm trying to write a function/method to add an item to an array. I can print out the addition from within the function/method but it's not updating the array. I figure the issue is in the function/method call but I can't seem to work it out on my own. Here's the code (Please don't judge me XD):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string[] mangaArray = {"Ai Yori Aoshi", "Monster Musume", "Interviews with Monster Girls"};
   AddToArray(mangaArray, "Corpse Party");
   PrintArray(mangaArray);      
}

static void PrintArray(string[] myArr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myArr.Length; i++)
    {
       Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] {myArr[i]}");
    }
}

static Array AddToArray(string[] myArr, string added)
{
    Array.Resize(ref myArr, myArr.Length + 1);
    myArr[myArr.Length - 1] = added;
    return myArr;
}
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Hint: your `AddToArray` method returns a value, but you're not using it in call to the method. (I would suggest you probably want to change the return type to `string[]`, too.) It's worth being aware that you're really not adding to an existing array - you're creating a new array which is slightly bigger, and assigning a new value in that *new* array.

Comment: pass array by ref: 
static Array AddToArray(ref string[] myArr, string added)

but, better, use List<string> instead string[]

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. I changed my method call to mangaArray = AddToArray... and it worked. I can't believe I didn't think of something so obvious.

Answer (score 2):

When changing `myArr` object inside the `AddToArray` method, the changes are only local and `mangaArray` will not be changed after returning to the Main method.

There are two approaches to address this issue.

1. Using ref keyword: You can mark a method parameter as a reference, wich persists the changes to the object when returning from the method.

```
static void AddToArray(ref string[] myArr, string added)
{
    Array.Resize(ref myArr, myArr.Length + 1);
    myArr[myArr.Length - 1] = added;
}
```

```
string[] mangaArray = { "Ai Yori Aoshi", "Monster Musume", "Interviews with Monster Girls" };
AddToArray(ref mangaArray, "Corpse Party");
```

2. Next options is to simply assign the returned value from the method to your array.

```
static Array AddToArray(string[] myArr, string added)
{
    Array.Resize(ref myArr, myArr.Length + 1);
    myArr[myArr.Length - 1] = added;
    return myArr;
}
```

```
string[] mangaArray = { "Ai Yori Aoshi", "Monster Musume", "Interviews with Monster Girls" };
mangaArray = AddToArray(mangaArray, "Corpse Party");
```

Comment: I changed the method call to mangaArray = AddToArry... but this 'ref' business looks like a MUCH better option. I was completely unaware of it. Thank you. :D

Answer (score 0):

You should pass mangaArray by reference in order to effect the changes to it:

```
AddToArray(ref mangaArray, "Corpse Party");
```

Then modify your method like this:

```
static Array AddToArray(ref string[] myArr, string added)
{
   Array.Resize(ref myArr, myArr.Length + 1);
   myArr[myArr.Length - 1] = added;
   return myArr;
}
```